# How may we show that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}={11\over 6}\cdot{1\over 10}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

proposed:

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}={11\over 6}\cdot{1\over 10}\tag1$$

**My try:**

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos^6(x)\over (\sin(x)+\cos(x))^6}\tag2$$

$u=\cos(x)\implies du=-6\cos^5(x)\sin(x)\ dx$

$${1\over 6}\int_{0}^{1}{u\over u^{1/6}+\sqrt{1-u^{1/3}}}\cdot{\mathrm du\over u^{5/6}\sqrt{1-u^{1/3}}}\tag3$$

Getting too complicated.

**How can we prove $(1)?$**

Comment: Note that $1+\tan x = 0$ for $x = \frac{3\pi}{4}$ so you need to be careful with substitutions.

Comment: Recall that $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}+ \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/4}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}+\int_{3\pi/4}^{\pi}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}$.

Comment: The function is not continuous on the interval. Maybe you seek the principal value.

Comment: Maybe the interval is $[0,\pi/2]$ instead of $[0,\pi]$. Please check carefully.

Comment: You right, thank you @xpaul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interval should be $[0,\pi/2]$ instead of $[0,\pi]$. Splitting $[0,\pi/2]$ into $[0,\pi/4]\cup[\pi/4,\pi/2]$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\tan x)^6}+\int_0^{\pi/4}{\mathrm dx\over (1+\cot x)^6}\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{1+\tan^6x\over (1+\tan x)^6}\mathrm dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{1+u^6}{(1+u^2)(1+u)^6}\mathrm dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{1-u^2+u^4}{(1+u)^6}\mathrm dx\\
&=&\int_1^2\frac{1-(u-1)^2+(u-1)^4}{u^6}\mathrm dx\\
&=&\int_1^2\bigg(\frac{1}{u^6}-\frac{2}{u^5}+\frac{5}{u^4}-\frac{4}{u^3}+\frac{1}{u^2}\bigg)du\\
&=&\frac{11}{60}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Nice approach as usual.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai, thanks.

Comment: Seems that, $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \dfrac{1}{(1+\tan x)^{2+4n}}$ is rational for $n\geq 0$ integer.

Comment: @FDP, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffe]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \bracks{1 + \tan\pars{x}}^{\,6}}}} =
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}{\dd x \over \bracks{1 + \tan\pars{x + \pi/4}}^{\,6}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}{\dd x \over
\braces{1 + \bracks{\tan\pars{x} + 1}/\bracks{1 - \tan\pars{x}}}^{\,6}} =
{1 \over 64}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\bracks{1 - \tan\pars{x}}^{\,6}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 64}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\braces{\bracks{1 - \tan\pars{x}}^{\,6} +
\bracks{1 + \tan\pars{x}}^{\,6}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 64}\pars{2I_{0} + 30I_{2} + 30I_{4} + 2I_{6}}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 32}\pars{I_{0} + 15I_{2} + 15I_{4} + I_{6}}
\end{align}

> where
>   $\ds{I_{n}  \equiv \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan^{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
> \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan^{n - 2}\pars{x}\sec^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x -
> \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan^{n - 2}\pars{x}\,\dd x = {1 \over n - 1} - I_{n - 2}}$.

---

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcccl}
\ds{I_{0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\pi \over 4} &&
\\[2mm]
\ds{I_{2}} & \ds{=} & \ds{1 - I_{0}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\phantom{-}1 - {\pi \over 4}} 
\\[2mm]
\ds{I_{4}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 3} - I_{2}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{2 \over 3} + {\pi \over 4}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{I_{6}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 5} - I_{4}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\phantom{-}{13 \over 15} - {\pi \over 4}} 
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

\begin{align}
\bbox[15px,#ffe]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \bracks{1 + \tan\pars{x}}^{\,6}}}} & =
{1 \over 32}\bracks{%
{\pi \over 4} + 15\pars{1 - {\pi \over 4}} + 15\pars{-\,{2 \over 3} +
{\pi \over 4}} + \pars{{13 \over 15} - {\pi \over 4}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 32}\pars{15 - 10 + {13 \over 15}} = \bbx{11 \over 60}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

To compute the antiderivative, *Bioche's rules* say we have to set $t=\tan x$. Indeed
$$\mathrm d t=(1+t^2)\,\mathrm d x,\enspace\text{so}\quad \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{ (1+\tan x)^6}=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+t^2) (1+t)^6}.$$
To obtain the integral of this rational function, obtain first the partial fractions decomposition
$$\frac1{(1+t^2) (1+t)^6}=\frac{At+B}{1+t^2}+\sum_{i=1}^6\frac{C_i}{(1+t)^i}.$$
This is most easily obtained  setting $u=1+t$, so that
$$\frac1{(1+t^2) (1+t)^6}=\frac1{(2-2u+u^2) u^6}=\frac{A'u+B'}{2-2u+u^2}+\sum_{i=1}^6\frac{C'_i}{u^i},$$
and performing the division of $1$ by $2-2u+u^2$ *by increasing powers* up to order $6$, so that
$$1=Q(u)(2-2u+u^2)+u^6R(u)\qquad(\deg Q(u)\le 5)$$
and finally
$$\frac1{(2-2u+u^2) u^6}=\frac{Q(u)}{u^6}+\frac{R(u)}{2-2u+u^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $x\mapsto \frac{\pi}{4}-x  $ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{(1+\tan x)^6} & =\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{d x}{\left[1+\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\right]^6} \\
& =\frac{1}{64} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(1+\tan x)^6 d x\\\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Expanding the integrand into  $3$ odd and $4$ even functions simplifies it into
$$
\begin{aligned}I&=\frac{1}{32} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(1 +\tan ^6 x +15 \tan ^2 x+15 \tan ^4 x\right) d x\\&= \frac{1}{32} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(1-\tan ^2 x+\tan ^4 x+15 \tan ^2 x\right) d(\tan x)\\& =\frac{1}{32}\left[\tan x+\frac{14 \tan ^3 x}{3}+\frac{\tan ^5 x}{5}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\\&=\frac{11}{60}  \end{aligned}
$$